How can I express this approximation for the modified Bessel function of the 2nd kind as an infinite sum?
Reading up on modified Bessel functions of the 2nd kind, it is stated in Bessel Functions Of the First and Second Kind, that we can approximate $K_{0}$ by the infinite product: $$ K_{0} =
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}\left[ 1-\frac{1^2}{8x}\left( 1-\frac{3^2}{2(8x)}\left( 1 - \frac{5^2}{3(8x)} \left(... \right)\right)  \right)\right]$$
Is there a simple way to write this using $\Sigma, \Pi$ functions? I can't find a nice way to write it but I feel it shouldn't be as tricky as I'm finding it.

Are you looking for an analytical expression or a numerical algorithm?

An analytical expression ideally, if one exists

There's a differential equation that defines them, right? That probably suggests a way to express them as a Taylor series. Seem to recall an integral expression for Bessel functions. Integrals imply sums.

Perhaps the formula is related to one of these formulas on the Wolfram Functions Site.

This is just a reformulation of the standard asymptomatic expansion of the modified Bessel function: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.E2

I believe the product $$f_k(x)=\left(1-\frac{1^2}{8x}\left(1-\frac{3^2}{2(8x)}\left(1-\frac{5^2}{3(8x)}\left(... \left(1-\frac{(2k-1)^2}{k(8x)}\right)\right)\right)  \right)\right)\tag{1}$$
can be evaluated as $f_k(x)=F_k(x,1)$ where $F_k(x,r)$ is defined recursively as
$$F_k(x,r)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 F_{k-1}\left(x,1-\frac{(2 k-1)^2}{k\, (8 x)}\, r\right) & k>0 \\
 r & k=0 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
and also as the sum
$$f_k(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^k \frac{(-1)^n\, \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\pi\, 2^n\, n!}\, \frac{1}{x^n}\tag{3}.$$
